# Why does my observable work in a service but not in a component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm trying to wrap my head around RxJs and Observables.

In my data.service.ts file I'm creating an observable like this:

```
export class DataService {
    private URLSubscription = new Subject();
    URLSubChange$ = this.URLSubscription.asObservable();

    changeFilters(filters: string) {
  this.URLSubscription.next(filters);
}
}
```

The changeFilters function is fired on user input.

Now, I have a component, datagrid.component.ts, that's importing the Observable.

```
import { DataService } from '../../core/data/data.service';

    @Component({
  selector: 'grid-app',
  templateUrl: './datagrid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datagrid.component.scss'],
  providers: [DataService]
})

constructor(dataService: DataService) {
    dataService.URLSubChange$.subscribe( url => {
        **some code**
    }
```

I'm doing a console.log in the subscription, but it never fires.

What's weird to me is that I have datagrid.service.ts file with the exact same code, and the subscription seems to be firing there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is something calling changeFilters so something is emitted into the stream? Also, since you are using the `providers` array in the component instead of registering the service with the root Angular injector, you may have issues with multiple instances of your service.

Comment: @DeborahK yes, I have another service that's doing an API call on input, and I'm trying to intercept that API call and pass it along to the component. I do have 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

on the data.service.ts file, so I think it's a singleton. Am I misunderstanding something? I've tried removing the providers array and it didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: To ensure it's a singleton, definitely leave off the component's providers array. With the code shown here, it's not obvious what could be wrong. Could you build a small stackblitz that demonstrates just the issue? Alternatively, try adding some tap/debug statements and/or use a debugger to see whether the value is being emitted.

Comment: Another possibility is that you're subscribing to the observable after it has emitted. To test it out, try changing your subject to ReplaySubject, i.e. `private URLSubscription = new ReplaySubject(1);` If that's the case, either keep the ReplaySubject in place or fix the execution order / business logic.

Comment: @DeborahK turns out it was indeed the provider array that was causing the problem, I just had to restart the dev server for the change to start working. Thanks for your help!